# Responsive Websites with "cover" background images

Tags: responsive-design, adobe-edge, reflow

I'm designing a responsive site using edge reflow with the following rules for breakpoints:

<480px, <768, 1024>

I'm using a different background picture for each breakpoint of respective widths. However when I add them to Reflow with `contain` for `scale-x` it seems as if the image I created is not that size. Most of them were at least 200 pixels shorter than designed.

So my question is what dimensions should I use background images for each breakpoint as well as any other guidance for this using Reflow or suggestions of I'm doing something wrong.

Normally I'd use `cover` rather than `contain` but then the image scales and doesn't show what I need it to from device to device.

Thanks